# How do I install PyTorch v1.0.0+ on Google Colab?

Tags: pytorch, google-colaboratory

PyTorch v1.0.0 stable was [released on 8 December 2018](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/releases/tag/v1.0.0) after being [announced 7 months earlier](https://code.fb.com/ai-research/announcing-pytorch-1-0-for-both-research-and-production/).

I want get a version optimised for the hardware that my IPython kernel is running on.

How do I get this version on Google Colab?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

try the following code snippet (it works equally for the runtime with or without gpu)

```
!pip install -q torch==1.0.0 torchvision
```

to check the version

```
import torch
print(torch.__version__)
```

here you have the version 1.0.0

**UPDATE**

```
!pip install torch
```

Works fine now, as the most stable version is `1.0.0`

Comment: Will this take into account the version of CUDA running on the system for optimisation?

Comment: I think it does, it tried `torch.backends.cudnn.version()` and the output was `7401` and  `torch.backends.cudnn.enabled == True` the output was `true`. I used the colab GPU runtime.

Comment: Great!  I also get `7410` even though [my solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53775509/5353461) is based on Google's colab code snippet and has `cu90` in the generated download URL.

Answer (score 5):

With version 1.0.0, PyTorch changed the download URL format from:

```
https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu92/torch-1.0.0-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl
```

to

```
https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu90/torch-1.0.0-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl
```

(The change is in the CUDA version part, where `cu92` changes to `cu90`.)

To programmatically generate that URL, I used the following code:

```
from os.path import exists
from wheel.pep425tags import get_abbr_impl, get_impl_ver, get_abi_tag

platform = '{}{}-{}'.format(get_abbr_impl(), get_impl_ver(), get_abi_tag())
cuda_output = !ldconfig -p|grep cudart.so|sed -e 's/.*\.\([0-9]*\)\.\([0-9]*\)$/cu\10/'    
accelerator = cuda_output[0] if exists('/dev/nvidia0') else 'cpu'

torch_url=f"http://download.pytorch.org/whl/{accelerator}/torch-{version}-{platform}-linux_x86_64.whl"
version='1.0.0'

!pip install -U {torch_url} torchvision
```

You can then change the `version` variable as desired as newer versions are released.

Answer (score 3):

You can now just

```py
import torch
```

No need for additional installation.

Answer (score 2):

For version 1.1.0, this works

```
!pip install -q torch==1.1.0 torchvision
```

Answer (score 2):

It worked for me you can try

```
!pip install torch
!pip install torchvision
!pip install mxnet-cu101
```

Comment: Actually, when I was installing pytorch using the 1st two commands it was showing error when I was importing but when I installed mxnet-cu101 it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a code to install pytorch. You can change it to whatever version you want.

```
!pip3 install http://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu92/torch-1.0.0-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl
```